# Show navigation icon without implementing navigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using a custom navigation drawer (or something similar) which doesn't extend the default NavigationDrawer. Therefore it doesn't automatically show the navigation button on the top left of the ActionBar. I would like to implement that functionality that normally comes with the NavigationDrawer.
I have tried many things, such as :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

or:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
```

or:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
```

but I just can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: why dont you create a custom toolbar and add button on that? later on click the button, you can show the navigation drawer with some animation

Answer (score 0):

Put the code into your styles.xml file:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `ActionBarDrawerToggle` like below to set home icon.

```
mToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ico_menu);
```

mToggle is Object of your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Comment: I don't have an ActionBarDrawerToggle because I don't wish to use a DrawerLayout, as the navigation I am using does not need it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by implementing a custom toolbar layout and using it as the supportActionBar.